# How to get image from wordpress database?

Tags: wordpress

I am new to WordPress technology.I want get and show images uploaded to WordPress theme.How can i show those images on my theme.

Can i loop through or any special command for that present in WordPress?

Comment: Where you want to display the images in the page template or somewhere??

Comment: on my page template

Comment: Is these images dynamic or you are going to display only single image per page bro.

Comment: dynamically i want to show

Comment: In the post page or some other pages. Pls be more clear where you want to show the images and on which page :)

Comment: Sorry for that.I just want to show images alog with post on template page.

Comment: @VijayKumarB: what you exactly want? if your simply want all the images then you can use `WP_Query` with `'post_type' => 'attachment'` argument, then it will get all the images from `wp_posts` table where all the post/page/image. etc are store.

Comment: @VijayKumarB: that means you want to show featured image in post or page, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve image in loop

```
the_post_thumbnail_url();                  // without parameter -> 'post-thumbnail'
the_post_thumbnail_url( 'thumbnail' );       // Thumbnail (default 150px x 150px max)
the_post_thumbnail_url( 'medium' );          // Medium resolution (default 300px x 300px max)
the_post_thumbnail_url( 'large' );           // Large resolution (default 640px x 640px max)
```

Wordpress save image separately as attachment and link with post meta

Answer (score 0):

You can get image from wordpress database -

There are four valid sizes built in to the WordPress core.

```
the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');       // Thumbnail (default 150px x 150px max)
the_post_thumbnail('medium');          // Medium resolution (default 300px x 300px max)
the_post_thumbnail('large');           // Large resolution (default 640px x 640px max)
the_post_thumbnail('full');            // Original image resolution (unmodified)
```

for **Blog Image** you can use -

```
<?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ): ?>
<?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' ); ?>
<img alt="Post Thumbnail" src="<?php echo esc_url($imageUrl[0]); ?>">
<?php endif; ?>
```

If you want to **set image size in code** you can use following code in function.php file

```
<?php add_image_size('product-size-large',300, 500, true);?>
```

then use this size here

```
<?php $imageUrl =  wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(),'product-size-large'); ?>
```

> Also, for more options see the [Codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/).